# Error in adding data to multi-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, sql, multidimensional-array

I want to read data from a data base, and put it in multi-dimensional array.
I don't know number of rows that will come from data base, and when i try to add new row to the multi-dimensional array i have the following error

```
Warning: array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array in C:\AppServ\www\web\commands\changeservice.php on line 101
```

and this is the code i have

```
function preparenewservices()
    {

                $managername = $_SESSION['managername'];

                $sqls = "select s.*,m.* from rm_allowedmanagers m inner join rm_services s on s.srvid = m.srvid where m.managername = '$managername' ";


                $sql = mysql_query($sqls);


                 $newservices =  array();


                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                  {
                        $nsrvid = $row['srvid'];
                        $nsrvname = $row['srvname'];                        
                        $nunitprice = $row['unitprice'];
                        $nunitpricetax = $row['unitpricetax'];

                        $ntotal = $nunitprice + $nunitpricetax;

                        $newservice = array($nsrvid, $nsrvname , $ntotal); 

                        array_push ($newservices[count($newservices)], $newservice);

               }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
array_push ($newservices, $newservice);
```

instead of:

```
array_push ($newservices[count($newservices)], $newservice);
```

because now you pass to the first argument of `array_push` an `integer` value not an `array`

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `$newservices[count($newservices)]` is not an array

Read docs here [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Just to fix the error you can do this

```
$newservices[count($newservices)] = array();
array_push ($newservices[count($newservices)], $newservice);
```

Comment: @str agreed. It will clarify user about the error and he can change the code according to his requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this code

array_push ($newservices[count($newservices)], $newservice);

with

$newservices[count($newservices)] = $newservice;

Comment: Arrays are zero-index, there is no need to increment it by one.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of adding an element/array to another array is this:

```
$newservices[] = $newservice;
```